# High-side 4-20 mA loop protector?

Tags: adc, protection, 4-20ma

Looking at the [MAX14626 4-20 mA loop protector IC](https://www.maximintegrated.com/en/products/power/protection-control/protection-ics/MAX14626.html), it's shown in the datasheet (Typical Operating Circuit, p. 1) being placed between the transmitter/transducer and an op-amp/ADC.

Is there a reason it's not placed between the power supply and the transmitter/transducer? Since the IC has a typical but temperature-dependent resistance, wouldn't it be simpler to always place it on the "high side" (provided it can handle the supply voltage)? This would obviate any potential need to account for its resistance and voltage drop.

For example, here is a circuit with the loop protector IC on the "low side" (of the transducer), with J1 being the supply (pin 1) and return (pin 2) of the transducer:

[image: loop protector IC after transducer]

Here's how I would think to do it, with the loop protector IC on the "high side", with J2 being the supply (pin 1) and return (pin 2) of the transducer:

[image: loop protector IC before transducer]

Is there something specific to 4-20 mA transducers (e.g. [this one](https://assets.omega.com/pdf/test-and-measurement-equipment/pressure/pressure-transducers/PX309.pdf), see p. 6 for 4-20mA version) that prohibits this? I thought their current draw (including device power) wouldn't exceed the output current (less, given the higher excitation supply voltage).

Comment: What are you trying to protect?

Comment: @user253751: only protecting the ADC in this case.

Comment: @Spehro: my application will be a self-contained system, but that is a fair point to keep in mind.

Comment: Suppose I just connect +24V wrt ground to J2 (+). R4 will dissipate over 5W, U6 will be destroyed (and possibly a bunch of other things connected to the 3.3V rail). Users will find the most destructive way to misconnect things, and often "forget" what happened after they fry things.

Comment: If it's self-contained then you might only need a protection on the ADC input.

Comment: @NickT if you are protecting the ADC from malfunctioning equipment connected to the port, then surely it makes sense the protection should be in between the ADC and the port?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This protection chip is made for PLCs.  Consider the number of connections in a large PLC panel.

In your case, your unit both measures the 4-20mA signal from the sensor and provides the power.  In a more general case, the power doesn't necessarily come from the same place where 4-20mA is measured.  Multiple sensors could be powered directly from terminals of an AC/DC converter. It's also conceivable to miswire and supply the sensor from some unprotected +24V rail.

I would keep the  MAX14626 on the input.
I would also consider the second protection IC (or a fuse, possibly PTC) on the +24V supply output.

Comment: "Consider the number of connections in a large PLC panel." Can you elaborate? I'm not familiar with PLC panels.

Comment: @NickT  Wiring in a PLC panel (or cabinet) [may look like this](https://www.electriciantalk.com/attachments/aefe3053-f419-468c-8336-a9ffe39f8c66-jpeg.157512/).  It's *not* a rat's nest.  There *is* rhyme and reason.  Nevertheless, there's plenty of opportunity miswire, especially during upgrades and maintenance.